# AngularJS - Show/hide based on number of items in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show, angular-ng-if, ng-hide

I have an ng-repeat with 2 filters:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat-start="addresses in Address.Entries | filter:{IsRegistered: true} | filterDate:'InfoDetails'">
        {{ addresses.name }}
        {{ addresses.number }}
        {{ addresses.email }}
        {{ addresses.contact}}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i add an ng-show or ng-hide to the  with class="container" to only show this element if the length of items repeated in the ng-repeat is greater than zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the filter results to a new variable in order to account for the length of the filtered list.

Then you can use the new variable to show/hide the section.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/gwjhrqk4/)

```
<div class="container" ng-show="filtered.length > 0">
    <div ng-repeat-start="addresses 
         in filtered = (Address.Entries 
                          | filter:{IsRegistered: true} 
                          | filterDate:'InfoDetails')">
          {{ addresses.name }}
          {{ addresses.number }}
          {{ addresses.email }}
          {{ addresses.contact}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What can be done if we are iterating on key-value pair and element should be hidden if it is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a separate function which will send back the true/false (which will determine the ng-show) in your controller.

Something like following,

```
<div class="container" ng-show="functionToDeterminetheState()">
   <div ng-repeat-start="addresses in Address.Entries | filter:{IsRegistered: true} | filterDate:'InfoDetails'">
{{ addresses.name }}
{{ addresses.number }}
{{ addresses.email }}
{{ addresses.contact}}
```

Comment: that function would have to run a filter in controller so how does that help? defeats the purpose of using `filter` in markup

Comment: This word work, just be careful.  Angular would continually evaluate this function and if the function is complex it could impact performance.